# Vue-Router is not supporting dynamic import() function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

The below code is throwing `unexpected token import`

```
const Router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/landing/landing') }
    ]
})
```

It is working if I do like below :

```
import landing from 'pages/landing/landing';
const LandingComp = Vue.component('search-product', landing);

const Router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '', component: LandingComp }
    ]
})
```

But I don't want to load all components initially. I wanted to load dynamically when it is required.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic imports are enabled by proper babel configurations. You have to properly configure babel. See [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import).

Answer (score -1):

```
import LandingComp = () => { 
    import landing from 'pages/landing/landing'
    Vue.component('search-product', landing)
}

const Router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '', component: LandingComp }
    ]
})
```

you can try it